# How do i execute the Java Program when i select the radio button

Tags: java

How do i execute the Java Program when i select the radio button

```
 class abc implements ActionListener {
   public static void main (String args[]){  

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame"); 
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Container contpane; contpane = frame.getContentPane();

        //added all  Radio  Buttons  
        JRadiobutton jb = new
        JRadioButton("test1");  JRadiobutton
        jb1 = new JRadioButton("test2");  
        jb.addActionListener( this ); 
        jb.addActionListener( this );//when i say "this" it is giving complie time
                  error becaus this keyword will not be accesible

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

  How do i create the JTextArea and
  Execute the Java class abc.java  in
  that JTextArea How do i add the 
  JTextArea to the panel and Frame

  what should i write inorder to execute
  the java class  say abc.java  


   } 
  }
```

Comment: The error message is correct as there is no "this" inside of a static method.  Solution: don't do that stuff in the static main method but do it within a non-static method or constructor as Bala shows you.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, restructure you code to create the frame and it's contents in your class's constructor like this

```
class abc implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new abc();
    }

    abc() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Container contpane;
        contpane = frame.getContentPane();

        // added all Radio Buttons
        JRadiobutton jb = new JRadioButton("test1");
        JRadiobutton jb1 = new JRadioButton("test2");
        jb.addActionListener(this);
        jb.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }
}
```

and I don't understand the other questions.

Comment: Bala R: How do i create the JTextArea inside the actionPerformed()  and add it to the panel and frame and Execute the Java Class inside this method